# Change condition in .htaccess file only affect directories that exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sites/all/b_([a-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ /sites/all/parent_theme/$2 [L]
```

Basically if the is no images under any directory starting with "b_" then it will attempt to take images from the "parent_theme" directory instead.

The problem is that it will also redirect to the "parent_theme" directory if the there is an attempt to access a directory starting with "b_" that doesn't exist.

How do I make the rule only work for directories that exist?

Thanks guys

Comment: so does the code below works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(sites/all/b_[a-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ /sites/all/parent_theme/$2 [L]
```